# Spell DC Saving Throws

Tags: saving-throw, dnd-next-playtest

In the Class sections, each class Spell DC is stated as "8 + your [Ability] modifier." So for example, a Mage with 16 Intelligence would have a Spell DC of 11. However, on page 28 of How To Play, it lists the Spell DC is "10 + your magic ability modifier." That would give our Mage a Spell DC of 13. Can someone clarify this for me, please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The How to play document has a typo.
It's DC = 8 + ability modifier + proficiency.

Comment: Looks like a bit of dried-on copy-pasta, that is, they copied the phrasing from 3.5 and forgot to change the numbers everywhere.

Comment: In earlier versions of the Next playtest the DC was 10+ it was later nerfed to 8+